# How to set a timeout to a listener in JS?

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have the following code in js:

```
var https_server = https.createServer(options, server);
https_server.listen(port, function() {
    if (!verbose) {
        console.log(`API is now listening on port ${port} on mode ${mode}`);
    }
    logger.info(`API is now listening on port ${port} on mode ${mode}`);
}).on('error', function(error) {
    if (!verbose) {
        console.log(`could not start server on port ${port}: ${error}`);
    }
    logger.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

If the password in `options` is wrong, it will wait for ever. How can I add a timeout for 1.5 mins that end up listener?

Comment: It seems you use a javascript framework, do you? Then please add an appropiate tag to your question.